# NgFor dont list my items in the mat-select html statement

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a class which get a list of object "Saison" and I want to list them to a select statement :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'jhi-saisons',
  templateUrl: './saison-home.component.html',
})
export class SaisonHomeComponent implements OnInit {

  saisonList?: ISaison[];

  constructor(protected saisonService: SaisonService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadAllSaisons();
  }

  /**
   * Charge toutes les saisons dans la propriété saisonList
   */
  loadAllSaisons(): void {
    const sortOrder = { sort: ['anneeSaison'] };

    this.saisonService.query(sortOrder).subscribe(
      (res: HttpResponse<ISaison[]>) => {
        this.saisonList = res.body ?? [];
      }
    );
  }

}
```

Saison has this model :

```
export interface ISaison {
  id?: number;
  anneeSaison?: string;
  estActiveSaison?: boolean | null;
}

export class Saison implements ISaison {
  constructor(public id?: number, public anneeSaison?: string, public estActiveSaison?: boolean | null) {
    this.estActiveSaison = this.estActiveSaison ?? false;
  }
}

export function getSaisonIdentifier(saison: ISaison): number | undefined {
  return saison.id;
}
```

subscribe return these values:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "anneeSaison": "2019",
        "estActiveSaison": false
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "anneeSaison": "2020",
        "estActiveSaison": false
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "anneeSaison": "2021",
        "estActiveSaison": true
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "anneeSaison": "2022",
        "estActiveSaison": false
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "anneeSaison": "2023",
        "estActiveSaison": false
    }
]
```

So in my html template, I use NgFor for put them in my select :

```
 <mat-form-field  apparence = "fill">
    <mat-label jhiTranslate="pdf4PwebApp.saison.dashboard.selectSaison">SELECT SAISON</mat-label>
    <mat-select >
      <mat-option *ngFor="let saison of saisonList" [value]="saison.id">
        {{saison.anneeSaison}}
      </mat-option>

    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

But ther is nothing in my mat-select statement :

[image]

Do you understand why there is no values ?

*PS : I use "Angular Material Design" (mat-select) and I follow this doc : https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview . I have also add this import in vendor.scss (for mat-slide-toggle statement).*

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

*Is there another specific import missing ?*

## EDIT 1

Result of Console.log from HttpResponse :
[image]
[image]

Comment: log `this.saisonService.query(sortOrder).subscribe()` response. I think your data is empty or there is a problem when casting the result.

Comment: Console log added

Comment: `this.saisonService.query(sortOrder).subscribe(
      (res: ISaison[]) => {
        this.saisonList = res.body;
      }
    );`
Try this to see if it works. If not, leave the 'res' as it is, without type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your html rendered before you get data, so try `*ngIf="saisonList"` on mat select

or write your return value in a getter
like this:

```
   get data(): ISaison[] {
    return this.saisonList;                                      
   }
```

and change saisonList in *ngFor to data(or any name you want to set for getter).

Comment: Thanks with function getter, I can view my values !

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no problem in your code~
So I guess `saisonList` is empty.
I suggest you try to use `json` pipe in your html, and check if `saisonList` do have value.

Comment: No, As mentioned above, saisonList is correctly supplied (my service is called and sends me the data in a array)